# getting the index of clicked item in a listview

Tags: android

I want to get the index of the Selected Item ( Clicked ) in a ListView.

Can any one please tell me?

Thanks
Deepak

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use an `AdapterView` and its onItemClick method :

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> list, View v, int pos, long id) {
        yourAdapter.getItem(pos);           
    }
});
```