# Android Radio Buttons issue

Tags: android

I am  using ListView which include one TextView and one Radio Button.. I use Custom Adapter Method to Inflate View..

I am having one Radio Button for each List....First i select Radio Button in List 1 then i select Radio Button of List 2.. If i select Radio Button of List 2 previous selection should be disabled.. Also i want to get the Position of radio Button selected which is inside the List..

My UI will be in this way:

---

LIST 1:

### TextView                     RadioButton

LIST :2

### TextView                     Radio Button

MY code:

class MultiLine extends BaseAdapter implements RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener
        {

```
        LayoutInflater mInflater;       
        String name;
        String TAG = "MultiLine";
        int i = -1;
        int j = -1;
        int k = -1;
        String[] VAL_CardNumber;

        public MultiLine(Context context, String[] value1) {
            try {

                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                VAL_CardNumber = value1;


            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "dom" + e);
            }

        }

        public int getCount() {

            return VAL_CardNumber.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

        public long getItemId(int arg0) {
            return arg0;
        }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.credit_card_list_view,null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.credit_card_listtext);
            //holder.mRadioGroup=(RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu);

            //holder.icon = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deal_icon);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.deal_title);
            //holder.mRadioGroup=(RadioGroup)convertView.findViewById(R.id.menu);
        }


        holder.text.setText(VAL_CardNumber[position]);

        //holder.mRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);


         iconContextMenu.setOnClickListener(new IconContextMenu.IconContextMenuOnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(int menuId) {
                    switch(menuId) {
                    case MENU_ITEM_1_ACTION:

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You've clicked on menu item 1", 1000).show();
                        credit_card_edit=true;
                        Log.v("Test", "YES BOSS COMING INSIDE A");
                           //startActivity(new Intent(Credit_Card_List.this,Credit_Card_Main.class));
                        break;
                    case MENU_ITEM_2_ACTION:
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You've clicked on menu item 2", 1000).show();
                        credit_card_delete=true;
                        Log.v("Test", "YES BOSS COMING INSIDE B");
                         // startActivity(new Intent(Credit_Card_List.this,Credit_Card_Main.class));
                        break;
                    case MENU_ITEM_3_ACTION:
                        credit_card_change=true;
                        Log.v("Test", "YES BOSS COMING INSIDE C");
                         // startActivity(new Intent(Credit_Card_List.this,Deal_Purchase_Checkout.class));
                        break;
                    case MENU_ITEM_4_ACTION:

                        break;  

                    }
                }
            });



        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        list_selected_position=arg1;
        credit_card_list.getPositionForView(arg0);
        credit_card_list.getCheckedItemPosition();
        Log.v("test",""+credit_card_list.getSelectedItemPosition());
        Log.v("tes1111",""+credit_card_list.getCheckedItemPosition());

    }




    }
```

Comment: edit your question, and re-format the XML u posted. put 4 consecutive spaces before pasting XML so that it appears here as a code, and is formatted. its such a pain to read it as of now

Comment: <TextView android:id="@+id/credit_card_listtext" android:textSize="15sp" android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="20dip"
            android:ellipsize="end" android:layout_marginTop="15dip" android:text="Deal Title" />
    <RadioGroup  android:id="@+id/RadioGroupTips"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    
  <RadioButton     
    android:id="@+id/option1" />
          
        </RadioGroup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I got until now, you should get what you want from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405369/getting-the-index-of-clicked-item-in-a-listview). The trick is to set up a click listener for the list, and that listener should check if the RadiusButton of the line clicked is checked or not. I don't know if you have your XML files correct, but this solution I pointed it works (sorry not to put code, but I'm also in the middle of an Android project and kind of busy).

Comment: No friend i want to get the position of Radio button pressed.. Its returning -1 for all selection in Radio button which is in List

Comment: If I got it right, you have (in pseudo-structure):
<listView>
   <radiusButton1><textView0>

Comment: <LIST VIEW><TEXT VIEW>< RADIO BUTTON>

Comment: I put your code but problem is that the OnClickListener for ListView is not happening.. If i select the Radio Button the List click is not working...

Comment: You are saying that, refering to the code I pointed, the `pos` is showing as `-1`? If that's so, that is reather odd...