# How to get selected item index in android listview?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [getting the index of clicked item in a listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3405369/getting-the-index-of-clicked-item-in-a-listview)

I have a listview, and I want to get the selected item index to do some process on it

how can I get this index as an integer value ?

this is my code:

```
final ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    list.setClickable(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

      }
    });
```

thanks all

Comment: Try reading the documentation or searching for a duplicate question.

Comment: `int position` is that you need.

Answer (score 4):

The variable `int position` in `onItemClick()`'s arguments contains what you want.

Answer (score 4):

If you mean index as the position of the item, `int position` is what you need.

Comment: I try to use it, but nothing appears when I use this value!